# Шестиугольник с рамкой и изображением на фоне

Tags: html, css

Как можно с помощью сss и html создать шестиугольник c картинкой внутри и границами?
[image: hexagon]

Answer (score 6):

Самый простой способ - сделать на SVG:

```css
.block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 252px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.block svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 252">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%">
      <image xlink:href="http://backgroundlabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/dandelion-seeds-pattern.png" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
    <path fill="url(#img)" d="M75.173,251.959L0,126.152l74.827-126l150-0.193L300,125.766l-74.827,126L75.173,251.959z"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

---

Немного погуглив, можно найти вот такой интересный вариант на чистом CSS (правда, при добавлении `border` рамка немного кривоватая выходит):

```css
.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 110px;
  height: 190px;
  background-image: url('http://backgroundlabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/dandelion-seeds-pattern.png');
  background-position: center center;
  z-index: 1;
  border: #000 solid 1px;
}

.hexagon .face1,
.hexagon .face2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
  border-top: #000 solid 1px;
  border-bottom: #000 solid 1px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.hexagon .face1:before,
.hexagon .face2:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  background: inherit;
}

.hexagon .face1 {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.hexagon .face1:before {
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(-60deg) translate(40px, 40px);
}

.hexagon .face2 {
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}

.hexagon .face2:before {
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(60deg) translate(-40px, 40px);
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon">
  <div class="face1"></div>
  <div class="face2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: неплохо но мне нужно именно такой как у меня у вопросе то есть перевернутый.

Comment: @user259708 обновил ответ

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с `clip-path`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hexagon {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000;
}

.hexagon:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  background: #ccc url(http://webneel.com/daily/sites/default/files/images/daily/09-2014/6-nature-photography-pedraterrinha.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hexagon,
.hexagon:before {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(75% 0, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 50%, 25% 0);
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}

.hexagon:hover,
.hexagon:hover:before {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 38%, 82% 100%, 18% 100%, 0% 38%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 38%, 82% 100%, 18% 100%, 0% 38%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hexagon"></div>
```